# AudioKit crash - How to play audio file with it?

Tags: ios, swift3, audiokit

I'm trying to play a sound file such as
/Users/NEO/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/D21A7767-E6F6-4B43-A76B-DC6E0F628B16/data/Containers/Data/Application/3F8A82F6-739F-40EA-BEA9-DF3560D0D8BB/Documents/Remember-When.mp3

I'm using AudioKit/Swift 3, here are my code:

```
do {
        debugPrint(sound.filePath)
        let audioFile = try AKAudioFile(forReading: URL(fileURLWithPath: sound.filePath))
        player = try AKAudioPlayer(file: audioFile)
        player.play()
    }catch let exception {

    }
```

the Xcode crash and console said:
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'com.apple.coreaudio.avfaudio', reason: 'required condition is false: _engine->IsRunning()'

I tried with AVAudioFoundation so It's work well.

```
do {
        player = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: sound.filePath))
        guard let player = player else { return }

        player.prepareToPlay()
        player.play()
    } catch let error {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
```

Could you give me an advise ?

Comment: [Here are a few matching posts](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=required+condition+is+false%3A+_engine-%3EIsRunning%28%29) on the error.

Answer (score 5):

I believe when ever you receive "'required condition is false: _engine->IsRunning()'" the AudioKit engine hasn't been started yet. So calling `AudioKit.start()` prior to playing should solve your issue